# SQL Stacked SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, select

Very new to SQL, hopefully this is straightforward!

I have Tables: Job, Task, Plan.
Task Contains Job.ID as a Foreign Key.
Plan contains Task.ID as a Foreign Key.

I need to return all Plan rows Where Plan.TaskID is equal to the results of a search which returns all Task.ID's Where Task.JobID is equal to the results of search which returns all Job.ID's From a search on the Job table where Job.Name = 'X'

I am not sure if i should be using JOIN statements, or somehow nesting SELECT statements.  Lots of trying, lots of errors. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, it's pretty easy. Multiple Joins should do the trick:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PLAN P, TASK T
WHERE P.TASKID = T.TASKID
AND T.JOBID = 'X'
```

you could also use the operator `JOIN` instead of multiple where clause, as you prefer.

EDIT: I made a little mistake. You need the jobName equal to 'X' and not the jobId. Just add the job table and a where clause:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PLAN P, TASK T, JOB J
WHERE P.TASKID = T.TASKID
AND T.JOBID = J.JOBID
AND J.JOBNAME = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to explain in just an `INNER JOIN`. This will give desired result:

```
select * 
from Jobs j
join Tasks t on t.JobdID = j.ID
join Plans p on p.TaskID = t.ID
where j.name = 'X'
```